# Console errors 'Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' of '(DENY || SAMEORIGIN)'

Tags: iis-7, https

Site iframes are throwing Chrome console errors 'Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading pages over https.  The error is '(DENY || SAMEORIGIN)' is not a recognized directive.  The header will be ignored.

This is happening on some of our IIS web servers and I can reproduce the error on my local by specifying the erroneous value above as an http response header but none of the affected servers has this response header set.